# How to correctly obtain a list of element of a table related to another table by a relation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, sql-server

I am pretty new in the using of database and I have the following problem.

I have these 3 tables: **Server** (that represent a server), **Cpe** (in wich every row represent a specific product) and **Server_Cpe** (that relate toghether the Server's rows with the Cpe's rows)

So I think that it means that: at a single row of **Server** could be related 1 or more rows that are into **Cpe** and that at a single row of **Cpe** could be related 1 or more rows that are into **Server**.

Is it right?

So I have these 3 tables:
[image]

Now in my application I have the following classes that maps the previous table: **Server** and **Cpe**

The **Server** class contains the following properties:

```
public virtual List<CPE.CPE> cpeList { get; set; }
```

that represent the list of CPE related to the specific **Server** instance (take from the **Cpe** table)

Now, into a manager class, I have to implement a method that populate a **Server** oject.

So for a specific Server object I have to obtain all its related **Cpe** object.

What can I do to perform this operation?

I am thinking that I could do something like this:

1. For a specific Server into **Server table** I obtain the list of the related **cpe_id** into **Server_Cpe table**
2. Then I iterate on this list obtaining the list of all the related cpe object insite **Cpe table**
3. Finally I put the reference to this list as my cpeList in my Server class

Is it the right solution or could I do it better in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx).

That way the db tables are converted to objects which you can then manipulate using LINQ queries.

For instance, to get a list of CPEs for each server you would write something like this:

```
using (YourDbContext db = new YourDbContext()){
    return (from s in db.Servers
            join s_c in db.Server_Cpe on s.server_id = s_c.server_id
            joim c in db.Cpe on s_c.cpe_id = c.cpe_id
            select c).ToList();
}
```

This will get you a list of all cpes which you can then encapsulate in a property in your server class like so:

```
public List<Cpe> Cpes{
    get{
        return ...above query
    }
}
```